# Woocommerce auto cancel on-hold after X days

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Since I will be using offline payments (bank billets - standard in Brazil). What I am trying to achieve is to auto-cancel "on-hold" orders after 9 days, which is when the billet expires. I found a few references of code: one from [woocommerce github](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/18191) and another from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41036070/filter-woocommerce-cancel-unpaid-order). What the code does (kinda messy in my opinion) is mirror the "pending" cancelation to "on hild". On github they are saying that it's important to use date_modified arguments to pull orders from the last hour. I have tested this out but it's not working. Do not know what the problem is.

```
    <?php

    function wc_foo_cancel_unpaid_onhold_orders() {
        global $wpdb;

        $held_duration = get_option('woocommerce_hold_stock_minutes');

        if ( $held_duration < 1 || 'yes' !== get_option( 'woocommerce_manage_stock')) {
            return;
        }

        $unpaid_orders = wc_foo_cancel_unpaid_onhold_orders( strtotime( '-' . absint( $held_duration) . ' MINUTES'. current_time( 'timestamp')));

        if ( $unpaid_orders) {
                foreach ( $unpaid_orders as $unpaid_orders ){
                        $order = wc_get_order( $unpaid_order);

                    if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cancel_unpaid_order', 'checkout' == $order->get_created_via(), $order ) ) {
                        $order ->update_status( 'cancelled', _( 'Unpaid order cancelled - time limite reached.', 'woocommerce'));
                    }
                }
        }

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_cancel_unpaid_orders', 'wc_foo_cancel_unpaid_onhold_orders');

function wc_foo_get_unpaid_onhold_orders( $date ){
    global $wpdb;

    $args = array(
    'date_modified' => '>' . ( time() - HOUR_IN_SECONDS ),
    'status' => 'on-hold',);
    $orders = wc_get_orders( $args );

    $unpaid_orders = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
    SELECT posts.id
    FROM {$wpdb->posts} AS posts
    WHERE posts.posts_type IN ('" . implode( "','", wc_get_order_types()). "')
    AND posts.post_status = 'wc-on-hold'
    AND posts.date_modified < %s
    ", date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', absint( $date)) ) );
}

?>
```

Comment: @LoicTheAztec that is part of the original code: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/6853605/34050032-593eb1b2-e1b1-11e7-8d8e-468dc52ad282.png

Comment: It's replicating the original wc_cancel_unpaid_orders (from what I understand

Comment: It's basically what Webdados is trying to achieve here: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/18191

Comment: Anyway, your replication can't output anything… I will look at that and let you know…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec true... I ran around the internet and got a bit of help with what I want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

So I had a little bit of help form @danaharrison at Wordpress.org to achieve this. So the code only applies to 'on-hold' orders.

```
 // To change the amount of days just change '-7 days' to your liking.

function get_unpaid_submitted() {        
                global $wpdb;

                $unpaid_submitted = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
                        SELECT posts.ID
                        FROM {$wpdb->posts} AS posts
                        WHERE posts.post_status = 'wc-on-hold'
                        AND posts.post_date < %s
                ", date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-7 days') ) ) );

                return $unpaid_submitted;
        }

        // This excludes check payment type.
        function wc_cancel_unpaid_submitted() {        
                $unpaid_submit = get_unpaid_submitted();

                if ( $unpaid_submit ) {                
                        foreach ( $unpaid_submit as $unpaid_order ) {                        
                                $order = wc_get_order( $unpaid_order );
                                $cancel_order = True;

                                foreach  ( $order->get_items() as $item_key => $item_values) {                                
                                        $manage_stock = get_post_meta( $item_values['variation_id'], '_manage_stock', true );
                                        if ( $manage_stock == "no" ) {                                        
                                                $payment_method = $order->get_payment_method();                                        
                                                if ( $payment_method == "cheque" ) {
                                                        $cancel_order = False;
                                                }
                                        }                                
                                }
                                if ( $cancel_order == True ) {
                                        $order -> update_status( 'cancelled', __( 'Pagamento não identificado e cancelado.', 'woocommerce') );
                                }
                        }
                }        
        }
        add_action( 'woocommerce_cancel_unpaid_submitted', 'wc_cancel_unpaid_submitted' );
        /* End of code. */
```