# woocommerce_cancel_unpaid_orders filter is not working on live - Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, server, cron, localhost

***The below code is working fine on localhost but is not working on live server***

The code is used to Mark all unpaid order as 'Failed' if the payment is not received even after 10 minutes of order creation

The code is a modified version of code taken from [Woocommerce plugin (line 852 to 877)](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-order-functions.php)

```
// Unpaid orders marked as Failed if payment is not received even after 10 minutes of order creation

    function custom_wc_cancel_unpaid_orders() {
        $held_duration = strtotime( '-10 minutes');
        $data_store    = WC_Data_Store::load( 'order' );
        $unpaid_orders = $data_store->get_unpaid_orders( strtotime( '-10 minutes', current_time( 'timestamp' ) ) );
        if ( $unpaid_orders ) {
            foreach ( $unpaid_orders as $unpaid_order ) {
                $order = wc_get_order( $unpaid_order );
                if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cancel_unpaid_order', 'checkout' === $order->get_created_via(), $order ) ) {
                    $order->update_status( 'failed', __( 'Unpaid order marked failed - time limit reached.', 'woocommerce' ) );
                }
            }
        }
        wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'woocommerce_cancel_unpaid_orders' );
        wp_schedule_single_event( time() + ( absint( $held_duration ) * 60 ), 'woocommerce_cancel_unpaid_orders' );
    }
    add_action( 'woocommerce_cancel_unpaid_orders', 'custom_wc_cancel_unpaid_orders' );
```

***Can someone tell me why it works on localhost but not on live server?***

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Hello @dipmala, I do not see any specific errors. The status of unpaid orders changes to 'failed' on localhost but do not change to 'failed' on the live server.

Comment: Then you need to debug the code what you get in unpaid order list and all?

Comment: What do you mean by 'debug the code'? It is not showing any syntax errors or any other kind of error notice. Do I need to go through Woocommerce logs or something to debug the error?

Comment: You need to check what is the result in  $unpaid_orders  if its cron then set email function so you can get that result in email.

Comment: What you are suggesting is beyond my skillset.

Comment: you need to put some efforts here I gave you the way so you need to track in your code.

Comment: Sure, I will try. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this plugin and use a cron job for function: **woocommerce_cancel_unpaid_orders_woo**

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: WooCommerce Cron Proxy
 */

add_action( 'woocommerce_cancel_unpaid_orders_woo', function() {
do_action_ref_array( 'woocommerce_cancel_unpaid_orders', func_get_args() );
}, 10, 10 );

?>
```